# Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, batch-file, msbuild

I have a batch file that calls `MSBuild` and builds three Visual Studio solutions:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

MSBuild solution0.sln  /property:Configuration=Release
MSBuild solution1.sln  /property:Configuration=Release  
MSBuild solution2.sln  /property:Configuration=Release
```

This works fine. However, I want to prompt the user to select a version of the program to build. Depending on the user input we build a particular set of solutions.

My problem is that if I modify the `PATH` variable after calling `vcvarsall`, I am no longer able to call `MSBuild`.

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
set /P version="Enter the version number [1] or [2]:"

IF %version% == 1 (
    set PATH="%PATH%;%PATH_TO_VERSION1_LIBS%"
    MSBuild solution0_v1.sln  /property:Configuration=Release
    MSBuild solution1_v1.sln  /property:Configuration=Release   
    MSBuild solution2_v1.sln  /property:Configuration=Release
)

IF %version% == 2 (
    set PATH="%PATH%;%PATH_TO_VERSION2_LIBS%"
    MSBuild solution0_v2.sln  /property:Configuration=Release
    MSBuild solution1_v2.sln  /property:Configuration=Release   
    MSBuild solution2_v2.sln  /property:Configuration=Release
)
```

I get the following error:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.
ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.
```

This is puzzling because the environment variable `VS100COMNTOOLS` is defined.

Comment: Get rid of those double quotes in the PATH assignment.

Comment: @HansPassant I added the double quotes because I'm on a 64-bit machine. Directories with special characters such as `C:\Program Files (x86)` will break the batch commands.

Comment: It doesn't break the PATH environment variable, embedded spaces are fine.  The ; semicolon makes it unambiguous.  Have you tried it or are you just assuming it doesn't work?

Comment: By special characters, I was referring to the parentheses. See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2771431/1538531

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might be a parsing error, try:

```
IF "%version%"=="1" set "PATH=%PATH%;%PATH_TO_VERSION1_LIBS%"
IF "%version%"=="1" (
    MSBuild solution0_v1.sln  /property:Configuration=Release
    MSBuild solution1_v1.sln  /property:Configuration=Release   
    MSBuild solution2_v1.sln  /property:Configuration=Release
)

IF "%version%"=="2" set "PATH=%PATH%;%PATH_TO_VERSION2_LIBS%"
IF "%version%"=="2" (
    MSBuild solution0_v2.sln  /property:Configuration=Release
    MSBuild solution1_v2.sln  /property:Configuration=Release   
    MSBuild solution2_v2.sln  /property:Configuration=Release
)
```

Comment: You are correct, sir! Sorry it took me a while to get back to you. I didn't understand how your answer would solve the problem. The parentheses around the `set` command appear to have led to a parsing error.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Inside a code block enclosed by parentheses you don't have access to `%variables%` except you use `delayed expansion` . **And** delayed expansion does not work _outside_ the batch script for `MSBuild`.