# ValueError ['path'] failed building wheel for python-crfsuite

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel, crf, python-crfsuite

I am trying to install python-CRFSuite using this command:

```
pip install python-crfsuite
```

Before this I use

```
SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%
```

since I am using Visual studio 2015. After running the installation command i get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsall
      raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
  ValueError: ['path']

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for python-crfsuite
```

If someone has faced same problem or has installed crfsuite on windows has knowledge about this then please help me solve this error

Comment: [Here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/distutils/msvc9compiler.py#l287) is the code that's raising the exception. Maybe a close reading will help clarify things.

Comment: If I'm reading it right, `vcvarsall.bat` is called during installation and its stdout is read. This script contains or generates environment variables. These variables are parsed and put into a dictionary called `result`. At the end of the function, the length of `result` is compared to length of `set(("include", "lib", "libpath", "path"))`. If they don't match, this error is raised: `ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))`. It seems three environment variables are missing (there's only `path` in `result.keys()` in your traceback). You could try running `vcvarsall.bat` to see what it outputs.

Comment: @jDo: thanks for your input on this. i tried running the vcvarsall.bat on cmd but got this <br/> ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.

Comment: I tried another workaround. Installed Mingw from this link https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/   and then used this link https://www.versioneye.com/python/python-crfsuite/0.8.1 to install pycrfsuite using the command : `pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/python-crfsuite/python-crfsuite-0.8.1.tar.gz ` and it worked!! I don't understand exactly why though

Comment: Cool. You could make your comment an answer and accept it. As you mention, it doesn't explain the original error but it might still be helpful for the next person who runs into this issue. If you still want to figure out and solve the original error, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491797/cannot-determine-the-location-of-the-vs-common-tools-folder) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461275/vs2010-command-prompt-gives-error-cannot-determine-the-location-of-the-vs-comm) if you haven't already.

Comment: I don't know if you want to solve this now that you got it working but FYI the error might be caused by `vcvarsall.bat` or another `.bat` file in the chain that overrides the `VS90COMNTOOLS` variable you've manually set and tries to fetch the value from the registry instead. If `c:\system\windows\system32` is not in the `PATH` variable, the script cannot find the registry and fails. If this is the case, adding/setting `c:\system\windows\system32` to `PATH` might solve the issue. I'm not on Windows so I can't test it though.

Comment: I addded `c:\windows\system32` to my `PATH` variable and executed the pip command. But it didn't help `error  building 'pycrfsuite._pycrfsuite' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for python-crfsuite
  Running setup.py clean for python-crfsuite
Failed to build python-crfsuite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried another workaround. Installed Mingw from this link http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files and then used this link http://versioneye.com/python/python-crfsuite/0.8.1 to install pycrfsuite using the command :
 `pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/python-crfsuite/python-crfsuite-0.8.1.‌​tar.gz`

and it worked!! I don't understand exactly why though